# PM2 run task requiring 'sudo'

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a task that must be run using sudo (sets up a listener on a low port).
Is there a way to specify this in a pm2 json start file declaration?

Comment: have you consitert looking in to a solution where you can bind to the ports with out sudo?

Comment: After reading your comment VeXii I did some looking and wound up using setcap to allow node to access low ports.  Works fine so far

Comment: good to hear. maybe write up you're process and post it below so other users might be able to benefit from it :)

Comment: Will do, as time allows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research after VeXii's comment and found one way to get access to privileged ports that works for me.  on an Unbuntu system,

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2
```

Then arrange for setcap to be run before node is started.  in my case I put the following in rc.local, but it could be run from .bashrc or .profile in a user account by adding 'sudo' to the comand.

```
setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/nodejs
```

What this does is to allow any program run by node to access any privileged port on the system.

I'd like a finer grained solution but this got me going.